# Jump to Error Handler when unprotecting worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I protect and un-protect my worksheets with VBA code found on the web.

Protection:

```
    Dim pwd1 As String, pwd2 As String
    pwd1 = InputBox("Please Enter the password")
    If pwd1 = "" Then Exit Sub
    pwd2 = InputBox("Please re-enter the password")

    If pwd2 = "" Then Exit Sub

    'Check if both the passwords are identical
    If InStr(1, pwd2, pwd1, 0) = 0 Or _
    InStr(1, pwd1, pwd2, 0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Password not matching. Please retry."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Protect Password:=pwd1
    Next

    MsgBox "All worksheets Protected."

Exit Sub
```

Unprotection:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrorOccured

    Dim pwd1 As String
    pwd1 = InputBox("Please Enter the password")
    If pwd1 = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd1
    Next
    MsgBox "All sheets UnProtected."

    Exit Sub

    ErrorOccured:

    MsgBox "Sheets could not be UnProtected - Password Incorrect"
Exit Sub
```

The protection works fine.  The unprotection, with correct password input, was successful yet the macro still jumped to the `ErrorOccured` error handler and displays the message

> Sheets could not be UnProtected - Password Incorrect

still appears.

What was the problem?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Change the `On Error GoTo ErrorOccured` to `On Error GoTo 0` temporarily. This will let you know which line is causing the error and what the error is.

Comment: @PeterT Hi.  Done accordingly. **ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd1** this line caused the error.

Comment: I found the unprotection was successful only to some worksheets, while some still left unprotected.

Comment: @ZackE Hi.  I am new to vba and still trying around some codes from the web.

Comment: @ZackE I am writing a workbook with worksheets of different functions.  Some of my tasks involve unprotecting SOME of the worksheets.  I don't want to do the unprotection on those worksheets one-by-one.

Comment: Do you always run `Protection` UDF before running `Unprotect`? **Hint**: IT's good practice to always use `Option Explicit`

Comment: Your unprotection sub has two `Exit Sub` rather than an `Exit Sub` to escape the main body and mark the start of the error handler, and an `End Sub` to mark the end of the whole code.  I'm guessing this is an error with you copying the code into SO - the code won't compile or run as it is.  Have you missed some code out when pasting here?

Comment: @Zac yea I'm afraid I always protect worksheets, then un-protect them when needed.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yea I also notice the two Exit Sub.  They seem weird to me as layman.  I checked the code I copied and the copying should be okay.

Comment: I think the Analyze-it add-on may be the trouble-maker.  I re-loaded my workbook before adding pages generated from Analyze-it and test the codes again, they worked perfectly.  Everything started to become strange after I made some worksheets involving Analyze-it commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use these for years:

```
Sub Schutz_ALLE_mit_PW_Abfrage()

nochmal:
pw1 = InputBox("Passwort eingeben")
pw2 = InputBox("Passwort nochmal eingeben")

If pw1 = pw2 Then GoTo los
If MsgBox("Passwortwiederholung war falsch", vbRetryCancel) = vbRetry Then GoTo nochmal
Exit Sub

los:
For Each blatt _
In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo weiter

If blatt.ProtectContents Then GoTo weiter
    blatt.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True, Password:="mb_neu", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
        blatt.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
        blatt.EnableAutoFilter = True
        blatt.EnableOutlining = True
weiter:
Next
End Sub

Sub Schutz_ALLE_weg()
pw1 = InputBox("Passwort eingeben")
For Each blatt _
In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
blatt.Activate
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=pw1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your code.  On my workbook, an error still occur.  And the problem was still about the pw1.  My workbook recognized the password for unprotection as incorrect (though I am sure the password I entered was the correct one).

Answer (score 0):

I have found something simpler. Every time the user commit a mistake, the error msg will pop up. The user can commit several mistakes, and the "Debug window" will not stop your code. Substitute *[YOUR_SHEET_NUMBER_HERE]* for the sheet you want (e.g.,*Sheet1*)

```
On Error GoTo password_request
    While [YOUR_SHEET_NUMBER_HERE].ProtectContents = True
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheet4.Unprotect
        
        If [YOUR_SHEET_NUMBER_HERE].ProtectContents = True Then
password_request:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        End If
    Wend
```